# excel cell value comparison from two sheets in the same workbook

Tags: excel

i have an excel combobox created as a list with datavalidation to display status. I am keeping the same status in sheet3 as well. When user click on the Validate button on sheet1, I need to compare the status from sheet1 and sheet3 and if there is a change I have to show an alert to add Date for the change. Also I need to make sure all cells in the given area are filled and none is blank. This is what I done so far, but unable to do the comparison.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NoOfCols As Long
Dim NoOfCells As Long
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim EmpNo As Long
Dim NewStatus As String
Dim ActualStatus As String
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With
    LastRow = LastRow - 8
    NoOfCols = Range("A5:G" & LastRow).Columns.Count
    NoOfCells = LastRow * NoOfCols
    LastRow = LastRow + 4
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5:G" & LastRow)) < NoOfCells Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all details"
    Else
        Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
        For StartRow = 5 To LastRow
            EmpNo = Cells.Item(StartRow, 3)
            NewStatus = Cells.Item(StartRow, 6)
            With ws
                Set FindRow = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=EmpNo, LookIn:=xlValues)
                MsgBox FindRow
            End With
        Next StartRow
        MsgBox "Data Successfully Validated"
    End If
End Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Make *sure* to qualify `Cells()` with the sheet you expect that cell to be on.  Otherwise, it's going to just use the ActiveSheet whatever that may be

Comment: Which cells are the status in?  Where in your code do you need to make the comparison?

Comment: In order to compare from two sheets, Do I have to set active workbook and  worksheet for every row? I need to compare the value in third column of sheet1 with second column in sheet3.